# Infinite Loop with while function and I can't debug it

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, infinite-loop

Here's my code (Python 2.7)

```
##Pay off a credit card in one year. Find a monthly payment using bisection search.
balance = 1234
annualInterestRate = .2
apr = annualInterestRate
month = 0
high = (balance * (1+apr))/12
low = balance / 12
testBal = balance
ans = (high + low)/2

while abs(testBal) > .001:
    testBal = balance
    ans = (high + low)/2
    while month < 12:
        testBal = (testBal - ans) * (1 + apr / 12)
        month += 1
        print month, testBal , ans
    if testBal < 0: #payment too high
        high = ans
    elif testBal > 0: #payment too low
        low = ans
    if testBal < 0:
        high = ans
print ans
```

I'm using a nested while function. The month counter works, but after the first loop, it gets hung up some where and I don't know why.

One thing that I've been able to find is that the variables low and high are both changed to ans. It shouldn't do that, again, I don't understand why.

Clearly, I'm a new programmer. This is a class assignment, so while I'm sure there are better methods to achieve this result. I need to stay with this basic format.

Anyone want to take a crack at setting this rookie on the right track?

Cheers!

Comment: You never reset month to 0 after the first iteration of your while loop

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you both.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  The older question suffers from a cognate problem (not changing the controlling variable of the bisecting loop), but not the same one.  The OP got *that* part right, but missed re-initializing the control variable of the computation loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set **month** back to 0 at the top of the outer loop.  It gets to 12 the first time, and then never resets.  Like this:

```
while abs(testBal) > .001:
    month = 0
    testBal = balance
    ans = (high + low)/2
    while month < 12:
        ...
```

Also note that you've checked twice for the balance being too high.

---

Other review notes:

1. You've misused the term apr; you should change it to something accurate.  The actual APR = (1 + annualInterestRate/12) ** 12
2. You recompute (1 + apr / 12) every month; this doesn't change throughout the program.
3. Your **month** loop should be a **for**, not a **while**.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Please remember to "accept" your favourite answer so that SO can properly retire the question.

Comment: [blush]  Sorry -- that's my standard text.  I see that I'm the *only* answer.  :-)  Still, please do something appropriate to keep the question from hanging as "open".